# standard form to vertex form of a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given the quadratic
$$-\frac{-1}{28}v^2+4v-80$$. and want to convert it into vertex form. I was unable to do it so I looked up the answer and found that in vertex form my equation is $$\frac{1}{28}(v-56)^2+32$$. I then factored the vertex form out and tried to work backwards,
$$\frac{1}{28}(v-56)^2+32 = \frac{1}{28}(v^2-112v+3136)+32$$
$$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\frac{1}{28}v^2+4v-112+32$$
$$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\frac{1}{28}v^2+4v-80.$$
My question is when working backwards, how do I know to separate $-80$ into $-112+32$, I am completely lost.

Comment: Are you not familiar with the process called *completing the square*?

Comment: $ax^2+bx+c=a\bigg(x^2+\dfrac bax\bigg)+c$$=a\bigg(\bigg(x+\dfrac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2-\bigg(\dfrac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2\bigg)+c$$=a\bigg(x+\dfrac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2-\dfrac{b^2}{4a}+c$

Answer (score 1):

You have some sort of minus sign issue on the leading coefficient.  I'll work this as if the two minuses cancel.

To "complete the square" you need to factor the coefficient of the leading term out of the first two terms:

$$\frac{1}{28}(v^2 +112v) -80.$$

Compute the square of half the coefficient of the linear term and then add and subtract that inside the parens:  $(112/2)^2 = 3136.$

$$\frac{1}{28}(v^2 + 112v+3136 - 3136).$$

The first three terms inside the parens is a square of a binomial:

$$\frac{1}{28}((v+56)^2+3136) - 80=\frac{1}{28}(v+56)^2+\frac{3136}{28}-80$$

$$= \frac{1}{28}(v+56)^2 +32.$$

Notice that I have $+56$ and you have $-56.$ This is because of the minus sign issue.

In general, since we know that $(x+r)^2 = x^2+2r+r^2$, if we see $x^2+bx$, and want a binomial square, we know that $b=2r$, so $r=2/b$.